# Is there a NoSQL system that also runs on windows and can be used for in-memory unittesting?

Tags: tdd, nosql, couchdb, redis, in-memory-database

I am looking for a NoSQL / key-value store / schemaless data storage system that runs on windows (at least for development) and has the ability to run in an in-memory-mode (without disk access). The in-memory mode will be necessary for rapid execution of test suites of the client software that we are building.

In production the data will be huge and has to be stored on disk.

For example **riak** has an in-memory option, but riak cannot compile and run on windows.

There should be client libraries in various languages available, or an http or xml-rpc interface or similar.

I believe **couchDB** [cannot run in-memory](http://www.rubyflow.com/items/3441), [neither](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1153%22neither%20mongoDB%22) **mongoDB**.

**Cassandra** installs on windows, but for non Java clients I am not sure if it is necessary to have Thrift and [this would be difficult to compile](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/503354792/getting-started-with-cassandra-on-windows%22to%20difficult%20to%20compile%20Thrift%22)

**Hadoop** can be setup as a development system on windows, but it seems it runs only on disk.

Comment: That post regarding Cassandra is somewhat misleading. It is certainly true that compiling thrift on windows might be troublesome but most client libraries for cassandra come with pre compiled thrift bindings and work right out of the box. That said, I'm not sure Cassandra is what you are looking for, since it is not completely trivial to run in an embedded fashion and does not have a memory only mode.

Comment: Why does it have to be NoSQL?  What about, say, SQLLite?  I only ask because you don't seem to care about the functionality of the NoSQL system, so I suspect that you are not planning on using it for the production data storage for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/). It is written in .NET and runs on windows plus [it has an inmemory option](http://ayende.com/blog/4662/ravendb-managed-storage)

Answer (score 2):

Since you relaxed the requirement on map/reduce, Redis seems a good fit.

1. Redis is an in-memory datastore, so your unit tests will be fast.
2. Officially, it is not supported in windows. However, Windows ports are available, and the general verdict is that these ports are good enough for local development.
3. Redis does not support Map Reduce natively, but then you have relaxed this requirement.

Comment: Thank you Sripathi, this is interesting, I will investigate further on redis.

Comment: Your 3 points sound like Redis does fit. You said in the beginning "Redis doesn't meet your needs". Is it a mistake maybe?

Comment: I looked into redis. It was easy to install it on windows, there is a zipfile and you start a server and a client exe-file and it just works. I worked through the tutorial. Very beautiful software. But what I did not know, it is a complete in-memory database. That's not what I want, it should have its storage disk based. I need the in-memory mode only for unittesting. But the production data will not fit into memory.